# Изменить размер картинок JS

Tags: javascript

Нужно с помощью яваскрипта поменять размер у всех картинок на странице. Никак не получается.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umb54r4a/1/)

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img').forEach(function() {this.style.width='400px'});
```

На [jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/pd8u7e32) работает, но нужно сделать на чистом JS.

```
$('img').each(function(){$(this).css('width','400px')});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) elems[i].style.width='400px';
```

`document.getElementsByTagName('img')` - получает коллекцию элементов img

Способ 2:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.images, function(myImg) {
  myImg.style.width='400px';
});
```

Comment: Да, всё работает. Спасибо, использую ваш код.  
Но всё равно остался интерес, возможно ли решить данную задачу с помощью метода forEach()?

Comment: @Марина добавила в ответ вариант с forEach()

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не сделать просто стилями?

```css
img {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://rta.customs.ru/nrta/images/stories/socset/F2.png">
<img src="http://rta.customs.ru/nrta/images/stories/socset/T2.png">
```

Или JS, но не перебирая все картинки?

```js
(function(d){
    var css = 'img { width: 400px; }',
        head = d.head || d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        s = d.createElement('style');

    s.type = 'text/css';
    
    if (s.styleSheet){
        s.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
        s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
    
    head.appendChild(s);
})(document)
```

```html
<img src="http://rta.customs.ru/nrta/images/stories/socset/F2.png">
<img src="http://rta.customs.ru/nrta/images/stories/socset/T2.png">
```

Comment: В моём случае нельзя изменять css стили и нужно изменять все картинки на странице, а не только эти две.

Comment: Второй мой пример динамически добавляет на страницу css, что избавляет вас от перебора всех картинок и повторного прохождения по новым картинкам, появившихся из ajax, например. Также от вероятного перерендеринга областей страницы при прохождении каждой картинки. Да и просто код быстрее работает

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByTagName() возвращает коллекцию, а не массив, потому не имеет метода forEach()

Comment: В идеале следует приводить и решение, не только объяснение источника проблемы. В таком виде ваш ответ больше похож на комментарий. Так как уже есть содержательные ответы, то я бы добавил это одинокое предложение в один из них (или откомментаировал, что, впрочем, вам пока недоступно).